# Chrome opens suggest password dialog on input with type number on MacOS?

Tags: html, angular, macos, google-chrome, angular-material

I'm running into an issue [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill).

I have `autocomplete="off"` on the entire form, and it does work correctly in Firefox, and most of the elements do work correctly in Chrome except for this one:

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput
          autocomplete="chrome-off"
            type="number"
            formControlName="leadTimeDays"
            placeholder="Lead time days">
        </mat-form-field>
```

I added `autocomplete="chrome-off"` to see if that might do the trick but it still populates the form dialog.  I tried build a [Stackblitz with the latest `@angular/material` but ran into this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70145415/adding-angular-material-to-the-current-version-of-angular-stackblitz), so I can only provide a screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas on how to disable the password autofill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got really really frustrated by this.  All of the various autocomplete off/false and various javascript answers didn't change this...

So I just changed the dang input box to a textarea, fixed the columns, set `rows="1"` and disabled the input from being adjusted...

I couldn't get any of these suggestions to work... so I just made my input a textarea, made `cols="1"` and disabled adjusting the space.

```
<textarea style="resize: none;" rows="1" cols="50" .... ></textarea>
```

No more suggestions from chrome...